# Android Studio Group File Template, Custom Path For Child File

Tags: android, android-studio, file-templates

Am trying to create a <kbd>Group File Template</kbd> which has to child files

- FragmentKotlinClass.kt

  - ViewModel.kt
  - fragmetn_layout.mxl

But the problem is that all three files created in the same directory
The question is How to specify the directory name in the `File Name Template`
for the `.xml` file to put it in `res/layout/`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can create file in upper directory by using upper directory prefix `../fragment.xml` or `../../fragment.xml`

So the challange is finding how many times we should go upper. I used $PACKAGE_NAME variable and some regex to solve this problem. First I go up until project root, then I go down to /res/layout/ and finally added my fragment file in snake case format.

So you can try this one-liner solution in your template's `File Name:`

```
#set( $LAYOUT_FILE = $PACKAGE_NAME.replaceAll("\.", "/").replaceAll("\w+","\.\.").concat("/../res/layout/").concat($NAME.replaceAll("([a-z])([A-Z]+)", "$1_$2").toLowerCase()) )${LAYOUT_FILE}
```